# Viewing version tree in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, ide, clearcase

Can anybody please tell me how to directly view the ClearCase version tree of a file opened in VS2008 ? I have the source control tool bar in the editor and it has all other option (check in, check out etc) but has no buttons to view the version tree of the file. Can I configure this some how ? Also, I have the clear case add-in dll which was working fine with my VC6 editor. Is there any way I can use this dll with VS2008?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post there any error messages you have seen during the ClearCase plugin installation process ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends where you did find your ClearCase plugin.

I just check with one of my ClearCase VS2008 user:

He has 2 tool bars (one CC UCM, one Base CC with the version tree button)

For VS2008, you need first to install the CC plugin like VS2005, then adds some files and .reg to update this installation to a VS2008 compliant CC plugin.

---

Here is our current ClearCase-VS2008 integration process:

Follow this [IBM technote](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21259189) if ClearCase is installed before VS .NET 2005/2003, in order to add **"`IBM Rational ClearCase Client for VS .NET`"** in the Custom Setup window step.

Get the CC-CQ-VS2008.zip mentionned this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24017991) and execute **"`reg_VS2008.bat`"**

---

Then tell me if you still do not see any "version tree" button.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. While installing I got couple of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add your own custom commands to the contextmenu.
http://randomconsultant.blogspot.com/2009/03/adding-clearcase-commands-to-visual.html