# Clearcase Remote Client in Visual Studio 2008 on a 64-bit client?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, clearcase

I've been trying to get the CCRC 7.0.1 client working inside Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 client.  Right now, it works inside VS2005 on the same client.  I've been following the instructions on [this support page from IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24017991), but haven't had any luck.  Has anyone gotten VS2008 working with the CCRC 7.0.1 on a 64-bit system?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have only see CC7.0.1 work with VS2008, but only in XP32 (like for the clients in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502436/viewing-version-tree-in-vs2008/503300#503300)).

All the installations and integration tricks with VS2008 I know about are in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404854/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-visual-studio-2008-sp1/1405021#1405021) (beginning with the same IBM technote you mention), plus some early advices in [this article](http://almmmm.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/how-to-integrate-visual-studio-2008-and-ibm-rational-clearcase/).